# Cannot get array to store input in next array slot

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm creating a banking system and can't seem to store the name of the customer names in an array. The last customer name is just overridden on the next customer. These are the lines concerning the array.

```
ArrayList<String> allnames1 = new ArrayList<String>();

System.out.println("Please enter account holders name:");

                    allnames1.add(sc.nextLine());

System.out.println("Account Created. Overview and Balance: " + "\n" + allnames1);
```

After this happens the user is taken back to the "Main Menu" in another class.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're creating new `ArrayList` each time instead of creating it once and adding new elements to it. However it's hard to say without other parts of code.

Comment: May be providing other part of code can help.This code does not give any picture of the cause of trouble.

Comment: Could you put full code of your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allnames1.add ("a")

allnames1.add ("b")   is enough.

If it doesn't work; I think its because allnames1 is newly created every time..  or sc.nextline is wrong.